# Python module install: specifying location of external library dependencies

Tags: python, pip

The `pip` tool makes python module install a breeze -- for the most part. But when the module requires some external C libraries that are not found in "standard locations", it can cause problem. Case in point: I was trying to install `gmpy2` python module, and it needs to have access to `gmp`, `mpfr`, and `mpc` libraries. On the system I'm using (Linux HPC, running RHEL 6.9), the system-wide libraries are very old. The HPC system admin provides more up-to-date libraries but not in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`. My question is: can we still use pip to build binary parts of the Python module? How to specify the custom include & library files location? I was forced to get back to `python setup.py` approach: first using `build_ext` subcommand, then invoking the `install` subcommand to finish the install. This is workable, but rather messy.

Comment: I do not know, what locations Python is looking by default, but what if you have those paths included in bash variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Aren't the programs usually searching for libraries using those locations as well?

Comment: Yes, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is searched for *running* the library. But for *building*, one has to use `LIBRARY_PATH` (at least for GNU toolchain?). For the compilation phase though, there is no such an alternative way of specifying path, AFAIK, other than the `-I` flags. Then maybe one has to use `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` to begin with.